# How can I see memory addressing of the Stack by example?

Tags: c, stack

I've read a bunch of times that the stack grows downwards from highest address to lowest address. I can't find any examples that show this though. So far I feel like I'm failing to find a way to even replicate it, though this could just be a fault of my own.

I tried to write an application to illustrate to myself visually the memory addressing of the stack in C, and to compare it against the heap.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const int _a = 0;
    const int _b = 0;
    const int _c = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int * pa = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int * pb = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int * pc = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    int i = 0;
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, &_a);     
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, &_b);     
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, &_c);     
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, &a);  
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, &b);  
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, &c);  
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, pa);  
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, pb);  
    i++; printf("%i -- %li\n", i, pc);  
}
```

When I run this I get the following:

```
❯ ./main
1 -- 140730484837108
2 -- 140730484837112
3 -- 140730484837116
4 -- 140730484837120
5 -- 140730484837124
6 -- 140730484837128
7 -- 94440756302432
8 -- 94440756302464
9 -- 94440756302496
```

My expectation was that I would see values 1 - 6 decreasing, because what I've read about the stack is that the values should start at the highest address and go lower. It always seems like the values increase.

I probably am doing something wrong, but I don't know what that would be or how to illustrate that new values on the stack are given lower addresses for each new value. Can anyone help show this visually? I've seen plenty of pictures, but I've never seen an example that is code derived that can show me this.

Comment: Use `%p` for pointers, not `%li`.

Comment: OT:  Regarding the calls to `malloc()`   1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @user3629249 Note that casting helps improve C++ compatibility.

Comment: The OP seems to be showing a misunderstanding.  The `stack` has no relationship to the `heap`

Comment: Not using %p is a mistake on my part, I'm sorry. The malloc statements were in there because I wanted to compare memory addresses of what was assigned on the heap and what was assigned to the stack.

Comment: @JL2210, makes no difference.  This is `C`, not `C++`.  Also, casting of the returned value 'often' results in errors when performing maintenance

Comment: Note: const values are neither on the heap nor on the stack

Comment: to visually see in which direction the stack pointer is moving,  use the appropriate compile option to have the compiler output a assembly file,   Note that the value of the stack pointer (typically `sp` )  is added to at the beginning of a function to make room for the local/auto variables and at the end of the function, the stack pointer is adjusted in the opposite direction to recover the stack room that was being used by the local/auto variables

Comment: @user3629249 It looks like the const values are unmodifiable stack values to me.

Comment: typically, 'const' values are defined in readonly memory (in older compilers, in the 'litorg' area), in modern compilers, they are either 'inlined' with the code or in the .data segment of the executable and loaded code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void stack(int count)
{
    int j;
    j = count;
    printf ("depth = %d, address = %p\n", j, &j);
    if (j < 9)
        stack (j + 1);
}

int main()
{
    stack(0);
}
```

Result, for me:

> depth = 0, address = 0x7ffc85c84114
>   depth = 1, address = 0x7ffc85c840e4
>   depth = 2, address = 0x7ffc85c840b4
>   depth = 3, address = 0x7ffc85c84084
>   depth = 4, address = 0x7ffc85c84054
>   depth = 5, address = 0x7ffc85c84024
>   depth = 6, address = 0x7ffc85c83ff4
>   depth = 7, address = 0x7ffc85c83fc4
>   depth = 8, address = 0x7ffc85c83f94
>   depth = 9, address = 0x7ffc85c83f64

Comment: true @david agree.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with declaration order of variables. A compiler knows stack requirements at the compilation time and is free to allocate variables in any order within the stack space. Moreover, it might not even allocate them on the stack.

I think the best way to demonstrate it is to ask the system to allocate stack dynamically. The way to do it is to use the `alloca` call.  So, here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char *a = alloca(8);
  char *b = alloca(16);
  char *c = alloca(32);

  printf("a=%p\n", a);
  printf("b=%p\n", b);
  printf("c=%p\n", c);

}
```